# spring data redis zadd with Long type key doesn't work

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to learn Redis here by doing some examples. I have an Entity called `DriverLocation` where it has a timestamp called `updatedAt` which is an epoch time with millisecond representation. The thing is I want to have a SortedSet so that I can do `zrangebyscore` queries to get last N records sorted by their timestamp.

sortedset will basically have `timestamp --> hash_id` structure. If I want to get records added last 10 minutes then I will do a `zrangebyscore` query to get all hash_ids in sorted manner. And then use `hmget` with hash_ids to get all hash objects.

Here is a very simple working demonstration on redis-cli where you can assume I used 3 digit numbers instead of milliseconds.

```
localhost:6379> zadd locations_0 213 hash_id_1
(integer) 1
localhost:6379> zadd locations_0 214 hash_id_2
(integer) 1
localhost:6379> zadd locations_0 215 hash_id_3
(integer) 1
localhost:6379> zrangebyscore locations_0 212 214
1) "hash_id_1"
2) "hash_id_2"
```

Everything works fine on redis cli. However, on Spring side I am not able to achieve what I am up for.

**DriverLocation.java**

```
@RedisHash("driverLocation")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DriverLocationEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Indexed
    private Long driverId;

    @GeoIndexed
    private Point point;

    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

**RedisConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisHost, redisPort);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisAtomicLong redisAtomicLong() {
        RedisAtomicLong redisAtomicLong = new RedisAtomicLong("DriverLocationIdCounter", redisConnectionFactory(), 0L);
        return redisAtomicLong;
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/drivers")
@Slf4j
public class DriverLocationController {

    @Autowired
    private DriverLocationRepository driverLocationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RedisAtomicLong redisAtomicLong;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DriverLocationEntity>> getDriver(@PathVariable("id") Long driverId) {
        long now = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();

        Set<Object> ids = redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rangeByScore(
                "locations_" + driverId,
                Instant.ofEpochSecond(now).minusSeconds(300).toEpochMilli(),
                Instant.ofEpochSecond(now).toEpochMilli());
        List<Object> driverLocations = redisTemplate.opsForHash().multiGet("driverLocations", ids.stream().map(id -> (Long) id).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(driverLocations.stream().map(dLoc -> (DriverLocationEntity) dLoc).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addDriverLocation(@RequestBody DriverLocationMessageEntity messageEntity,
                                                    @PathVariable("id") Long driverId) throws JsonProcessingException {
        long now = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        DriverLocationEntity driverLocationEntity = new DriverLocationEntity();
        driverLocationEntity.setDriverId(driverId);
        driverLocationEntity.setPoint(new Point(messageEntity.getLongitude(), messageEntity.getLatitude()));
        driverLocationEntity.setUpdatedAt(new Date(now));
        driverLocationEntity.setId(redisAtomicLong.getAndIncrement());

        String strVal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(driverLocationEntity);

        // save driver location entity
        driverLocationRepository.save(driverLocationEntity);

        // save timestamp -> hash_id
        redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add("locations_" + driverLocationEntity.getDriverId(), now, driverLocationEntity.getId());

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("done");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically managed this by using [Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) client with their `StringCodec`

```
        DriverLocationEntity driverLocationEntity = new DriverLocationEntity();
        driverLocationEntity.setDriverId(messageEntity.getDriverId());
        driverLocationEntity.setPoint(new Point(messageEntity.getLongitude(), messageEntity.getLatitude()));
        driverLocationEntity.setUpdatedAt(new Date(now));
        driverLocationEntity.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        // add hash_id into geoset for distance calculations
        redissonClient.getGeo(GEO_SET_KEY_NAME, new StringCodec()).add(messageEntity.getLongitude(), messageEntity.getLatitude(), HASH_ID_PREFIX + driverLocationEntity.getId());
```